# How to solve "CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check." without adding browser plugin

Tags: angular, http

I know this question is very frequently asked and 100% duplicate of other questions. I tried the solutions defined in them, but they didn't work for me.So please kindly lookat my question and help me out here.

I am trying to call a GET method at the url  `https://www.webwork-tracker.com/rest-api/reports/full-data?start_date=2020-06-22&end_date=2020-06-22` from my local which is on `http://localhost:4500` . I have defined `proxy.confs.json` and included the following lines in it,

```
"/rest-api" : {
"target" : "https://www.webwork-tracker.com",
"secure" : false
}
```

I call the url through this:

```
const username = 'user@gmail.com';
const password = 'userPassword';
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)});
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
return this.http.get<any>('https://www.webwork-tracker.com/rest-api/reports/' +
  'full-data?start_date=2020-06-22&end_date=2020-06-22', {headers});
```

I want to solve this without adding any browser plugins and I doesn't have the access to the backend server. So, the solution I found was adding proxy. But I still get the following error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.webwork-tracker.com/rest-api/reports/full-data?start_date=2020-06-22&end_date=2020-06-22' from origin 'http://localhost:4500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The API call works fine in the `POSTMAN`. And I understand the browser checks for the same origin before sending the get request as well. So the proxy helps me solve it. Can someone please help me to solve this?

Comment: did you allow cors on server?

Comment: I have no access to the server.

Comment: You need to allow cors on server then only this issue will get resolved there is code that you need to add in your server file like res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*") this depend upon the type of server you are using

Comment: but it works fine with the postman? only the browser has this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service, you need to call a relative url, which will then be proxied

```
return this.http.get<any>('/rest-api/reports/' + ...)
```

Also since you are accessing a server not on `localhost`, you need to set `changeOrigin` (see the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server))

```
"/rest-api" : {
"target" : "https://www.webwork-tracker.com",
 ...
 changeOrigin: true
}
```

**Other points:**

Make sure the proxy file `proxy.conf.json` matches the name in your `angular.json` (`confs` vs `conf`)

Also, `HttpHeaders` are immutable so your `headers.append` calls will have no effect (but you don't need them anyway)

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)});
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //no effect
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
```